# Apollo GraphQL (React) Data sharing across components

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I just started using react-apollo and was wondering what was the best way to share data across components.

For example, I have `componentA` which is using `grapql` from `react-apollo` to fetch some data (`WrappedA`). I also have some other component, `componentB`, somewhere else in my UI and want to use the data already fetched by `componentA`.
Attached a very simple example below.

```
const ComponentA = ({ ...props }) => (
    <div>
        ComponentA...
        id: {props.organisationsData.organisations.id}
    </div>
)

const ComponentB = ({ ...props }) => (
    <div>
    ****** Want to access props.organisationsData *****
    ComponentB...
    </div>
)

const organisationsQuery = gql`
    query organisations {
        organisations {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`

const WrappedA = graphql(organisationsQuery, { name: 'organisationsData' })(WrappedA)

const Container = ({ ...props }) => (
    <div>
        <WrappedA />
        <ComponentB />
    </div>
)
```

According to the apollo documentation (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#in-your-ui) ideally the query is tied to the UI component.

I can wrap `componentB` with the same `organisationsQuery` and it will use the cache but I wont be able to co-locate my query to my main UI part. I could not find any info related to sharing data across components.

When I tried

```
const WrappedB = graphql(gql`
    query organisations {
        organisations {
            id
        }
    }
`, { name: 'organisationsData' })(WrappedB)
```

(leaving out `name`) I saw an extra call made to the graphql endpoint.
This is not ideal.

What would be the best way to access data already fetched from the server? (using v2 so cannot use an existing redux store, accessing the cache manually seems low level and this use case is not mentioned on the site: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/caching.html)

Thank you.

Comment: The query is not needed by your main UI component, but by both of these A/B components. So it make no sense to colocate it with main UI component. As that component dont need anything from it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use apollo link  , this is local state management , you can read documentation

apollo-link-state allows you to store your local data inside the Apollo cache alongside your remote data. To access your local data, just query it with GraphQL. You can even request local and server data within the same query!

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html