# Fetch data for the entire app without depending on component logic

Tags: reactjs, redux

There are X routes in the frontend made with React-router and each of them drives to a component.

No matter which route is visited, I need to use some data from an api.

This data is constant through the application. Using Redux I could dispatch an action FETCH_DATA in each React component and manage the logic of fetching in Redux actions.

However, this looks repetitive to me because I would be writing the same logic through all the React components that need data: look for the the data in the store. If it's there take it. If it's not there, dispatch FETCH_DATA.

What is another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call that api in the `App.tsx` i.e. your first component to be rendered in the application. This is the component which actually holds the `Routes` also.

Consider the following code as an example and change it according to the need of your application:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ComponentDidMount() {
    this.props.callTheApiHere()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Routes history={this.props.history} />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now each component that any of your `Route` render have to just get the data from the `redux store` using `mapStateToProps` in `react-redux` `Connect`

Comment: This answer is a bit old but was useful. I marked it as accepted :)

I applied it with similar concepts but using hooks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL offers an elegant solution for this requirement of sharing data across components belonging to different routes.

**More information:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_kqcGW1jkY

[Apollo GraphQL (React) Data sharing across components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349355/apollo-graphql-react-data-sharing-across-components)